# Show UML Class diagram autopopulating class dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

In IntelliJ IDEa, one can quickly create an UML Class diagram for any class or a set of classes. You can add classes to the diagram via drag and drop or using `space` key for that.

Then you can show dependencies between the classes. However, I'd like to see what are all the classes that interact with some specific class. If I show a diagram of that class only, I'll only get some inheritance in that diagram, but dependencies associations are not shown. For that I need to drag in all classes that I know interact with the class and then show dependencies. Usually I would just drag the whole package in, expecting that there are classes that interact with this class. But that will bring in a whole lot more unrelated classes and then the diagram explodes.

Is there some smart way of adding just classes that directly interact with my class, so the diagram scope is more limited? E.g. all class interacting with a class from a certain package?

Comment: In the meantime, my best workaround so far is to set the layout to Radial, which should neatly lay out dependencies for a class around it. Visually it becomes easier to select everything else and remove it from the diagram. quirky, I know